# beforeShowDay don't disabled day in current month

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have this script:

```
var unavailableDates=["2014-09-22","2014-09-31","2014-10-17","2014-10-20"] ;
    function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
   alert(dmy);
  if ($.inArray(dmy, a) < 0) {
    return [true,"enabled","Book Now"];
  } else {
    return [false,"disabled","Booked Out"];
  }

}
$('#datedepart').datepicker({

       dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
       beforeShowDay: unavailable,
minDate:3});
```

my problem days "2014-10-17" and "2014-10-20" disabled but not "2014-09-22" and "2014-09-31"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date.getMonth() returns months smaller than 10 as single numeric value e.g 9 for september but 10 for october. You need to add an extra 0 as a string or remove 0's from your unavailableDates in month values like :

```
var unavailableDates=["2014-9-22","2014-9-31","2014-10-17","2014-10-20"] ;
```

Another issue is, you are searching in a while your array name is "unavailableDates".

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you want ?

```
dmy = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate();
```

And

```
$.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates)
```